How to associate frequency to a Series without 'Period' argument?

First I'v got a value warning that say "the date index provide has no associated frequency information".  So, I used ".to_period('D')" function.

However, it has generated a typeError : "float() arugment must be a strig or real number, not 'Period'.  I don't clearly understand this issue.  is there another way to associate frequency to my data variable in 1. to avoid TypeError in 2 ?


alternatives I tried :
errors.index = errors.index.tz_localize(None)"
errors.index = pd.date_range("2021-01-01","2023-04-01",freq="d")"

The code below
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    import yfinance as yf
    from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
    from datetime import datetime
    from datetime import date
    from datetime import time


# Define the start and end dates for fetching the stock data
    start = '2021-01-01'
    end = "2024-03-22"

# Fetch historical data for AAPL
    stock1 = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
    stock1_data = stock1.history(interval='1d', start=start, end=end)

# Fetch historical data for AMZN
    stock2 = yf.Ticker('AMZN')
    stock2_data = stock2.history(interval='1d', start=start, end=end)

# Calculate the log of the closing prices
    X = np.log(stock1_data["Close"])
    Y = np.log(stock2_data["Close"])

# Add a constant term for the linear regression model
    X = sm.add_constant(X)

# Fit the linear regression model
    model = sm.OLS(Y, X)
    results = model.fit()

# Extract the model parameters
    alpha = results.params.values[0]
    beta = results.params.values[1]

# Calculate the residuals/errors
    errors = Y - (alpha + X["Close"] * beta)

    errors.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(errors.index).to_period('D')

# Generate an AR model
    model = AutoReg(errors, lags=20)
    model_fit = model.fit()

# Make predictions
    forecast = model_fit.forecast(steps=24)



any hint would be helpful, thank you !
